# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

> I installed my newly developed application to a new a fresh PC and ERRORs come up for the first time, at first it needed a .Net 4.5 installation which i set from the installshield wizard. then this error came up. how do i run my developed apps in a fresh PC.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0n=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
   at ThesisCapstoneProject.mdlConnection.ExecuteQuery(String Query)
   at ThesisCapstoneProject.frmLogin.frmLogin_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ThesisCapstoneProject
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iskoba%20ng%20Pag-ibig/Dudays%20Pharmacy%20POS/ThesisCapstoneProject.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.20806.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34003 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34107 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

> if i install this (ThesisCapstoneProject) in my old pc where i developed the app, its working fine. but in my new fresh pc, i got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this 2 files.

1. System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll
2. System.Web.Extensions.dll

And it should be done, Also be sure to change the `Select Platform` to .NET

Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html)

Comment: how can i select platform to .Net? in my installshield wizard, i select required .NET 4.5, so it means i must install it from a fresh pc. and where i can find those 2 system.web..

Comment: not yet, i dont even know where to find that system.web.extensions, and the mysqlconnector is 6.8.4 only available in their site. btw i already installed it and yet no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69940/discussion-between-ethaan-and-mharveen-biu).

Comment: @MharveenBiu i was afk come to chanel, also lets delete comments

Answer (score 0):

Check your references, I'm not sure what IDE you are using but with visual studio 2012 it is in the Solution explorer under references. select the MySQL object and look at the properties it is probably because the .NET 4.5 is referencing a newer version. just un-install the old version of MySQL.Data and add the correct version, from your error it looks like you need to have MySQL.Data Version=6.8.3.0 installed.

Comment: in my VS2012 references its look like i installed correctly MySql.Data Version 6.8.3.0 from my old pc where i developed the application and i installed MySQL connector driver installed in my fresh pc but still no luck and same error came up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have MySQL and/or a MySQL Connector driver installed.  Here is the link for the [ODBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

> Connector/ODBC is a standardized database driver for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, and Unix platforms.

Comment: i installed mysql connector NET 6.8.4 in my fresh PC and still no luck. there is no 6.8.3 available in their site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the dll-File in your application directory? Maybe the two computers have a different system (x86 vs. x64). A dll-File is for x86 or x64 and not for both. You can also set a compile-option in your Visual Studio if you want to compile for "any", x86 or x64.